# WebSphere 7.0 Admin Console - Web Services

Tags: java, ibm, websphere, was7

I've been trying to search on Google (and IBM's documentation) to find the answer to this, and I haven't found anything.  Either my search skills aren't that great today, or my assumption is correct and the answer is no. I'd like to confirm with the experts on here, though.

Does anyone know if the WAS 7.0 admin console provides a REST API that we can call programmatically? I'd rather not have to use an instance of WAS and be forced to use wsadmin if I can use another language to script some things (like stopping or starting JVMs).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is technically no --  but you can build your own "thin" admin client that will allow you to run wsadmin commands from a system without a full-blown instance of WAS.

The setup is a bit arcane.  Full details here: http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-dist&topic=txml_adminclient

> With the Administration Thin Client, you can run the wsadmin tool or a
>   standalone administrative Java program with only a couple of Java
>   archive (JAR) files. This reduces the amount of time that it takes for
>   the wsadmin tool to start and improved performance. This information
>   should be used to set up JMX client programs.

If your shop is not already skilled with wsadmin, check out wsadminlib https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib and the consoles built-in command assistance http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0812_rhodes/0812_rhodes.html

Comment: Yeah... I had a feeling this would be the only answer.  They don't exactly make it easy for us.  Thanks!